# How can I build a T4 template automatically with each build while specifying a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, t4

I have a T4 template that generates a class that can be used at runtime to build a document. In the properties of the template file the custom tool is set to "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor", and I've also set a custom namespace for the custom tool namespace property.

If I right click on the template and choose "Run Custom Tool", or if I choose Build->Transform All T4 Templates the code is generated properly. However, I've been trying to get the template to generate automatically on build using the Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets build task as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/design-time-code-generation-by-using-t4-text-templates#Regenerating. When I do that, the file is regenerated, but it ignores the custom tool namespace.

So: how can I build a T4 template automatically with each build while specifying a namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured it out: the solution is to replace the `<CustomToolNamespace>` tag in the csproj file with a `<ClassNamespace>` tag.

Comment: Hi, having the exact same issue. can you elaborate? what tag did you replace?

Comment: @TomerW Super late, but my answer was unreadable due to bad formatting. Should be readable now.

Comment: ;) thanks... for matter of fact i figured another way.... i built a tool using Microsoft.Text.Templating that compiles the classes... but this seem more correct. i think i will redo that :)

Comment: Still, my csproj file has no <CustomToolNamespace> tag...
should i add a <ClassNamespace> tag, and Where? for each file? I dont get it, sry.

Comment: I figured this one out. If you go to the properties of the tt file, there is a "Custom Tool Namespace". Fill that in. Then you will see that the csproj file has changed and contains a `<CustomToolNamespace>` tag. Change that to `<ClassNamespace>`